# How can I make this code more efficient so that it runs quicker?

Tags: excel, vba, rows, show-hide

I am attempting to hide rows so that only a certain retailers data is shown, the data is not filterable due to the layout of the report. I start by just unhiding all rows as a reset and then manually hide rows that aren't relevant to a retailer until only the clicked retailers info remains.

However this is a slow way of doing this, and I need a quicker way I can understand. There is no criteria to filter the data. Just the retailer name on a click button.

My code shows the manual slow way of doing this.

```
Sub SummaryRetailer1Only()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Resets hidden rows by showing everything.
ActiveSheet.Rows("2:480").EntireRow.Hidden = False

'Hides all rows that don't show data for Retailer1.
ActiveSheet.Rows("18:21").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Rows("37:48").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Rows("54:57").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Rows("73:84").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Rows("88:129").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Rows("261:376").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Rows("390:393").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Rows("409:420").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Rows("424:427").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ActiveSheet.Rows("443:454").EntireRow.Hidden = True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The code works fine I just want a way that I assume uses some variables so that it runs quicker.

Comment: Well for one: `ActiveSheet.Range("18:21,37:48,54:57,73:84,88:129,261:376,390:393,409:420,424:427,443:454").EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: what about `Range("18:21,37:48,54:57,73:84,88:129,261:376,390:393,409:420,424:427,443:454").EntireRow.Hidden = True`?

Comment: oh! @JvdV you were faster! LoL

Comment: You can lose the `.EntireRow` you've already selected the whole `Row` with `Rows(...`

Comment: I did try this but it didn't work, will try again now (: Cheers both

Comment: Ok, so when I change it to be a line of numbers instead of 1 line per range it errors out on that line, whether I take out "EntireRow or not.

Comment: Nevermind, just noticed I had it saying "ActiveSheet.Rows" and I needed "ActiveSheet.Range" when doing it in this fashion. Is this the fastest it can be?

Comment: @Josh, yes it is to my understanding. Depends what you meant with `Variables` in your question. Can this range of rows be different assuming this example used `Retailer1`? In that case you might want to edit your question so we can have a better understanding of the layout of your data.

Comment: I don't know to be honest, I just imagined that to make it run faster would probably involve using variables.
What it's currently doing (with the above changes) is perfect, I just wanted to make it run as fast as possible due to my hardware being trash.

Comment: I've tried on some files and it takes seconds, so what it makes slower your macro could be calculations too heavy (but you turned it to manual, so it should not), your pc, or maybe are those rows linked to anything else? with linked I mean if they are the source data of a graphic, or an image taken with the camera tool

Comment: @Josh You should also try using explicit references to the worksheet you want to work with, instead of using `ActiveSheet`. So just use a `Worksheet` object and set it accordingly.

Comment: Another option would be if you could upload your file, so other people run your macro and can tell you how long does it take in their PC, maybe that can throw some light in this issue. Also, what is the **size** of your file?

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, my hardware is absolute trash so that is most definitely the main cause of the problem (and the main reason for me always trying to make any code i write as quick as possible).
It is definitely running faster than it once was with everyones help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SummaryRetailer1Only()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- It s better to create a with statement with the sheet you want to use insead of activesheet

        'Resets hidden rows by showing everything.
        .Rows("2:480").EntireRow.Hidden = False

        'Hides all rows that don't show data for Retailer1.
        Union(.Rows("18:21"), .Rows("37:48"), .Rows("54:57"), .Rows("73:84"), .Rows("88:129"), .Rows("261:376"), _
                .Rows("390:393"), .Rows("409:420"), .Rows("424:427"), .Rows("443:454")).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End With

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Would this run quicker than the above way?

Comment: The above code avoid *ActiveSheet* usage and combine all rows together.

Comment: It does the trick but union is an operation on it's own and can be avoided in this case to make it (even though it will be a fraction) faster.